# Where can I ask why installation of an Office 2010 package failed?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What's the appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask this question?

> Every time I visit [the download page](https://www20.downloadoffice2010.microsoft.com/usa/registerkey.aspx?ref=backup&culture=en-US) in order to download a backup up copy of both an "MS Office 2010 Home
> and Business" install and an "MS Office 2010 Home and Student" install,
> the EXE files they provide both give the following error upon
> execution:
>
> > The installation of this package failed.
>
> I have (and provide on the website) the valid license keys for both of these
> products.
>
> I don't know if it matters or not, but I am downloading the
> installation files on a Windows 7 64-bit machine, but trying to
> install them (one Home and Business and the other Home and Student) on
> two different XP 32-bit machines.
>
> I thought that the error could be caused by the website providing
> 64-bit Windows 7 installs because it read the specs of the machine
> that is downloading them. However, if I attempt to execute these
> installation files even on the machine that downloaded them, I still
> get that error.
>
> Also, if it matters, the browser used to download the installation
> packages is a fully up-to-date Google Chrome browser, *and* I have made sure to uninstall
> any previous versions of MS Office on the 32-bit machines

Is Super User the appropriate SE site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is the place to ask questions about:

- Specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking
- Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

That sounds like your issue to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you should be accepted on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com).

From their [what to ask](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software,
> - or personal and home computer networking

Sounds like your question would fit in.